# How do I set up a Hugo site on Github or Bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, hugo

I have been going in circles for days and would appreciate your help.

I used the Hugo quickstart guide to create a repo on my local machine: https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/

I cannot figure out how to push this to either Github or Bitbucket. My preference is Bitbucket bc they have private repos, but I ran into many SSH errors. So I thought I'd try Github and once that was up, to import that repo into Bitbucket, but I can't get it working on Github either.

This is what I was able to push to Github: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNiue.png)

It's missing the rest of the repository (archetypes, config, etc). I can see the files but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to deploy it to either Bitbucket or Github. Please help!

Comment: What kind of SSH errors?

Comment: This was two nights ago, so I'm not sure. I just tried this command:  

git add --all  

git commit -m 'hugo'  

and got this:
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Great, i can't for the life of me figure out line breaks in comments. Tried two spaces, didn't work.

Comment: Not sure `add --all` works in your case.  I haven't used that flag, but going off `man git-add` you actually want `-A` (although it's better to add files explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have created a local git repo at the root of your Hugo project: there should be a .git subfolder.

Make sure there is no other .git folder in the children or parent folders of that project.

Check your `git remote -v` output: you can use an SSH or HTTPS URL for your remote.
Check if you have any .gitignore files which might prevent adding the rest of the folder contents.

Finally, don't forget a branch new Hugo project has mainly empty folders: and `git add` won't add empty folders. Start adding some files in it first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167389/discussion-between-mmc-and-vonc).